# If $\alpha<\beta$, there exists a ordinal $\gamma$ such that $\alpha + \gamma = \beta$. Why?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I want to prove the following proposition.

**proposition**: Let $\alpha,\beta$ be ordinals. If $\alpha<\beta$, there exists a ordinal $\gamma$ such that $\alpha + \gamma = \beta$.

I am trying to prove this by  transfinite induction. However, I have some trouble with the case $\beta$ is a limit ordinal.(I know the definition of the sum of a ordinal and a limit ordinal)

please give me some ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers are fine, but since you explicitly asked for the limit case in a proof by transfinite induction, let's see how that goes as well.

Assume $\beta=\sup_{\delta<\beta}\delta$. By induction hypothesis, for each $\delta<\beta$ you can pick an ordinal $\gamma_\delta$ such that $\alpha+\gamma_\delta=\delta$. Now let $\gamma:=\sup_{\delta<\beta} \gamma_\delta$. Then $$\alpha+\gamma=\alpha+\sup_{\delta<\beta} \gamma_\delta=\sup_{\delta<\beta}(\alpha+\gamma_\delta)=\sup_{\delta<\beta} \delta=\beta.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\gamma$ be the smallest ordinal that satisfies $\alpha+\gamma\geq \beta$. Then you see $\alpha+\gamma=\beta$.

Otherwise, suppose $\alpha+\gamma>\beta$, it is obvious that $\gamma$ can not be $\eta+1$, so suppose it is a limit one. By definition of $\sup$, there is some $\eta<\gamma$ such that $\alpha+\eta\geq \beta$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then, we must proof that there exists $\gamma$ such that $\alpha + \gamma \geq \beta$. While $\beta$ itself would satisfy this inequality, the proof seems to be as difficult as that of my first proposition.

Comment: @Saito Similar but not the same I guess. Suppose $\gamma$ is the smallest one that $\alpha+\gamma<\gamma$. Obviously it is a limit ordinal. So $\alpha+\gamma=\sup_{\beta<\gamma} \alpha+\beta\geq \sup_{\beta<\gamma} beta=\gamma$

Answer (score 1):

As sets, $\alpha$ is a subset of $\beta$. Consider $C=\beta\setminus\alpha$, the set-theoretic difference. Then $C$ is a well-ordered set, having the same order type as some ordinal $\gamma$. Then $\beta=\alpha+\gamma$.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Why $\beta = \alpha + \gamma$ ?

Comment: I'd say "that's how ordinal addition works" :-) @Saito